# Need held with instancing a QWidget with PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt, instance

This code works:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


window1=QtGui.QWidget()
window1.show()

window2=QtGui.QWidget()
window2.show()
```

But this doesnt:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.w=QWidget()
        self.w.show()

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
window()
window()
```

How can i create 2 windows by instancing the class window? I don't get it with Qt, with Tkinter it is very easy to figure out...

EDIT: The question above is meant for creating some windows by clicking on a button in the systray. As you can see when executing the code below, it works, but there is just one window shown at any time, e.g. if i clicked twice the context menu of the systray icon to create two windows. I don't see where it comes from...

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class Note(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Note,self).__init__()
        self.w=QWidget()
        self.setWindowTitle("Note")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)

class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        self.trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon("J:\\python\\SimpleNotes.ico"), self.app)
        self.menu = QMenu()

        self.newWindow = self.menu.addAction("new Note")
        self.separator = self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.exitAction = self.menu.addAction("Exit")

        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.newWindow.triggered.connect(self.newNote)
        self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.menu)
        self.trayIcon.show()

        self.app.exec()

    def newNote(self):
        print("Create new note entry has been clicked")
        self.note=Note()
        self.note.show()

    def close(self):
        self.trayIcon.hide()
        self.app.exit()
        print("Exit menu entry has been clicked")

main()
```

EDIT2:
Got it! The problem can be solved by coding it this way:

```
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.notes=[]
        ...

    def newNote(self):
        note=Note()
        note.show()
        self.notes.append(note)
```

Though still I don't know why now it works, or even no window occurs if you delete the line "self.notes.append(note)". But hah, it works!

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://ralsina.com.ar/weblog/posts/BB990.html) for the "why" part: garbage collection. (You're missing the `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed` from my updated answer too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.w=QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
w1 = window()
w1.show()
w2 = window()
w2.show()
app.exec()
```

You need to show the top-level containers, not the internal widgets. And you *probably* wanted that widget to show inside your main window and not as an independent window.

The problem with your updated code is that when the click "Add note" a second time, you replace the member `self.note` with a new window. The previous window is therefore not referenced anywhere after the call, and gets destroyed.
If you want to keep multiple windows open, you need to keep a handle on all of them as long as you need them.

*Warning: I don't actually know python, so the naive use of a list might not be a good idea - I don't know.*

Try this:

```
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False);
        self.notes = []
        ...

    def newNote(self):
        print("Create new note entry has been clicked")
        note=Note()
        note.show()
        self.notes.append(note)
```

The `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed` part is necessary in your use case, otherwise `app.exec` would exit once you've closed all the note windows, and your app would exit at that point - doesn't look like that's what you want to happen.

Note: that's not a usual use of `QMainWindow`. That's a "heavy" class, usually use as the sole main window of a "complete" GUI app, with a menu, toolbar(s), status bar, etc. Using a simple `QWidget` with a `QTextEdit` and maybe a couple of buttons sounds better for this use case. In fact you could probably get away with deriving your `Note` from `QTextEdit` and implementing just a context menu.

Comment: Well thanks for your comment, but still there is something I need to figure out, perhaps you can find my mistake in the code, I've put it after my first question. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah thanks that was my attempt with tkinter, just a text widget with context menu. I didn't know yet what methods Qt delivers and which widgets. My whole note program is complete and running with tkinter, only that I cant figure out how to link the systray with the notes (because the notes only show if i close the systray, as if it would block the code somehow). So now i will try to port my few lines to Qt, still learning something new ;)

Comment: Ah just one more question: You wrote "The problem with your updated code is that when the click "Add note" a second time, you replace the member self.note with a new window.". So, if I just call the new note "note=Note()" and not "self.note=Note()", it won't be overwritten by a second note?

Comment: No, you'll get a different problem: the note will get destroyed after the method ends since it won't be references anywhere => it gets garbage collected. I don't know python so I don't know the exact garbage collection rules. I added a link to a blog post that describes this issue in my comment to your question. Adding a reference to the windows in a list keeps them alive.